# uk standard visa - how much money is needed in bank for indians

Tags: visas, uk

My case:
Country: India:
Need: Standard UK visa
Tickets: Tickets are already booked. Now i saw that that it's recommended not to book tickets prior to visa.  
Accommodation and food: Have a sponsor in UK
Query 1:
I have a consistent 1.5L-2L bank balance since 6 months, a job in MNC. We have 2 applications to make. I think the money is enough even if flight tickets were not booked but how much is the money they have as ballpark to decide whether it's enough or not ?
Query 2:
Is it ok to tell that I have already booked refundable airline ticket so 2L is ok ? i dont want them to think I'm trying to be overconfident about my visa so booked tickets in advance.

Thanks,
Pragati

Comment: Showing them air tickets is silly. Please read the linked infomration.